# SAXParser проблема с кодровкой

Tags: java, sax

Пытаюсь распарсить файл, java SAXParser

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<doc typeImport="hermes.dbside.models.descr_task.Task" uniqueImportId="2017_9_10_12_00_0">
    <tasks source="onese" org="">
        <task>
            <name>задача из вввфыпыфвп что иииииииииииииииимпта</name>
            <description>описание задач</description>
        </task>
    </tasks>
</doc>
```

Получаю ошибку `lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 237; White space is required between the processing instruction target and data.`

если использую варирую `<name>`, то могу получить ошибку `Element type "O" must be followed by either attribute specifications`, вероятно проблема с кодировкой, но не могу понять какая именно нужна

Comment: Сохраните файл в UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень странная ошибка, изначально читал посредством BufferedReader,
затем передавал строку в метод parse так `new StringBufferInputStream(str)`

теперь читаю так

```
File file = new File("task.xml");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

и в метод parse передаю is, видимо здесь `new StringBufferInputStream(str)` что-то происходило с кодировкой